# Have snowflake ALWAYS show commas (thousands separators) in Snowflake Snowsight?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, output

My Snowflake Snowsight never shows commas in data output (visually) - this would make it easier to compare millions and billions and other large numbers.

I see I can right click a specific field and make it 'show commas' as a one-off ... but --- to DEFAULT this feature to all numeric columns? There doesn't appear to be a setting.

Comment: Currently, there is no default setting for 'thousand separator' at account level or user level.